# php Как с помощю запроса сформировать таблицу

Tags: php, массивы, foreach

У меня есть массив информации из БД.

```
 array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
    ["partner_id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["name"]=>
    string(9) "Smiley TV"
    ["title"]=>
    string(5) "Speed"
    ["download"]=>
    string(4) "9510"
    ["upload"]=>
    string(5) "33775"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(5) {
    ["partner_id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["name"]=>
    string(9) "Smiley TV"
    ["title"]=>
    string(5) "Turbo"
    ["download"]=>
    string(4) "2427"
    ["upload"]=>
    string(5) "19696"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(5) {
    ["partner_id"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["name"]=>
    string(13) "Victory Media"
    ["title"]=>
    string(5) "Speed"
    ["download"]=>
    string(4) "4144"
    ["upload"]=>
    string(5) "80445"
  }
}
```

Как с помощью php сделать такую таблицу:
[image: Таблица]

P.S "name" может быть больше двух и они не должны повторятся.
Нужно для каждого name создавать колонку, а для каждого title - строку и заполнять ее данными по загрузке и выгрузке.
Помогите, пожалуйста, никак не могу правильно вывести!!!!!

Comment: А как вы обычно выводите массив?

Comment: Как вот тут - http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/638373/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%83-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%91%D0%94