# Как вывести таблицу из БД?

Tags: php, sql

Всем доброго времени суток.
Хочу вывести таблицу из бд в таблицу на странице,как можно это сделать?
в то уже всю голову сломал.

```
$options = array(
  PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
  PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
try {
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=cms;charset=UTF8', $db_username, $db_password,$options);
  global $pdo;
  $stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM users');
  $data = $stmt->fetchAll();
    echo "<pre>";
print_r($data);
echo "</pre>";
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Ошибка!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}
```

Всем заранее благодарю за ответ.
Что выводит print_r
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: print_r($data);  что возвращает?

Comment: @L.Vadim добавил к вопросу скрин,совсем забыл про него)

Answer (score 1):

Как то так

```
echo "<table>";


foreach($data as $key=>$value)
{
 echo "<tr>";
 echo '<td>' . $value['name'] . '</td>';
 echo '<td>' . $value['lastname'] . '</td>';
 ........
 echo "</tr>";
}


echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ,но мне чуть другое надо.
Как сделать цикл,чтобы таблица строилась полностью.
Понимаю,что можно просто перечислить столбцы,но можно же как-нибудь сделать,чтобы она автоматически строилась тип такого
https://goo.gl/YCTkvO 
Надеюсь понятно объяснил)

Comment: Добавьте к ответу код для выведения заголовков (их названия это ключи массивов) и будет вам счастье. Примерно так - $columns = array_keys($data[0]); echo '<tr>'; foreach($columns as $key => $value) { echo '<th>' . $value . '</th>' }; echo '</tr>';

Answer (score 0):

Может кому пригодиться

```
 echo "<table>";
foreach($data as $key=>$value)
{
 echo "<tr>";
 foreach($value as $row=>$val) echo '<td>'.$val.'</td>';
 echo "</tr>";
}
    echo "</table>";
```

Нам возвращается двумерный массив,мы с помощью первого цикла перебираем "1 уровень" массива,а потом заходим на "2 уровень" каждого индекса,как раз там и хранятся наши данные из БД.
Благодарю всех за активность в данном вопросе :)